# angular4-data-table fix the header

Tags: angular, datatable, row, fixed

I am using angular4-data-table in my application. I need to display a fixed header with the veritical scroll bar. I am already displaying the vertical and horizontal scrollbar by changing the table.template.ts file in angular4-data-table API.
Following is the way now the scrollbars(vertical and horizontal) are getting displayed.
 In the table.template.ts file, I am surrounding the table in a DIV which has scrollbars.
 Is there any way a property can be added in 'data-table > thead > tr > th {' class to make header fixed.

```
 <div class="data-table-box" [ngClass]="cssProp">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered data-table" >
        <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody
        </tbody>
        </table>
  </div>

  .cssProp{
  overflow-x:scroll;
  max-height:460px;
  width: 99%;
  }

  .data-table > thead > tr > th {
    ????
  }
```